# JavaScript library which like present Google+ Ripples

Tags: javascript, graph

I'm searching JavaScript library which give me ability like Google+ Ripples:

- Graph with items
- Scaling ability
- Perfect perfomance with 10 000 nodes and more

Like this: [screenshot](http://f.cl.ly/items/0K2c3U2v0B3P2C0N283r/Screen%20Shot%202012-01-09%20at%204.05.02%20PM.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google search provided me with these frameworks:

- [JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit](http://thejit.org/)
- [Protovis](http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/) seems discontinued and the new library is [d3.js](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/)
- [flare](http://flare.prefuse.org/) --> Flash based

They all have graph visualizations and you should be able to get what you are looking for.